# Best placement for action buttons on product comparison page

Tags: buttons, comparison, decision-making, product-details

I'm trying to decide the best place to display action buttons for the user. The user’s main goal is to monitor products in their current and track for better options.

The user is comparing products on the page. Essentially, viewing their current product alongside a potentially better product. Side by side comparison.

Once a decision is made the user can watch the item, notify a team member of this item, or hide this item for some time.

I’m trying to determine if the buttons should be placed...

- A) Top of the page next to the product name
- B) Middle near the content where the comparison is shown
- C) Bottom of the page after a decision is made

[image: Here’s a quick markup of the comparison page.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious answer is: test it with your users. However there are some best practices that I can provide for this situation.

The height of the product section is very important here. If they are equal then there should not be any issue as to where you place the button as long as it is visible at all times.

If the the product sections are very long, I would place the buttons on the top navigation and use fixed positioning so they are always on the screen as the user is scrolling down.

Regardless, just make sure they are vertically aligned and are visible at all times so that the user won't have to look up and down for the necessary button when the heights of the section is different.

Hope this helped!